# Get image type cell from excel

Tags: c#, excel-interop, excellibrary

I am reading data from excel sheet containing image in one cell of each row.
I have successfully read all data except image type of cell in C#.
I am using Interop.Excel library

Here is my excel sheet format:
[image]

Comment: tell how you insert image to cell please

Comment: Images are getting inserted from excel manually not from code, We need to extract only from code

Comment: i get it, but show the way you add them manualy. becose it depends how you can get export them then.

Comment: Select the cell, add desired image from Insert >Picture section. 
Each picture can be different and of random name but of specific size.

Comment: are you sure that your image associated with cell? I tried to add picture as you say and it pased as object not as cell value in excel.

Comment: Thats an interesting thought. I followed this link http://superuser.com/questions/117623/inserting-a-jpg-picture-into-a-cell-in-microsoft-excel-2007

But you mean to say, that we cannot add image in specific cell.which means if we cant add we cannot get